# Ensure execution order among redux subscriptions and componentDidMount

Tags: asynchronous, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

We have a web application by reactjs, redux, redux-saga, and stripe. We have this code in `models/subscription.ts`

```
  .subscript(({ dispatch, history }) => {
    return history.listen(({ pathname }) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'app/updateApp', payload: history });

      if (pathname == "/" || pathname == "/sign" || pathname == "/welcome") return;

      dispatch(removeActionNamespace(fetchSubscriptions({})));
      if (pathname === '/my-subscription') {
        dispatch(removeActionNamespace(fetchSubscriptionDetail(undefined)));
      }
    });
  })
```

And this code in a component `src/components/Page/index.tsx`

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.isLoggingInOrOut && this.props.isLoggedIn) {
      this.props.dispatch({ type: 'usage/read_usage' });
    }
  }
```

`fetchSubscriptions` fetches the subscriptions in stripe for the current user; if the user has not yet a customer in stripe, `fetchSubscriptions` will create a customer of stripe for it.

`read_usage` fetches past actions of the current user in the database. It also requires information from stripe such as the start date of the subscription of the customer.

So ideally, `read_usage` should be executed after the creation of a customer (i.e.,  `fetchSubscriptions`).

My test shows that the current implementation cannot guarantee this order of execution. Does anyone know how to restructure the code to achieve that?